# #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

while editing a file of mine called "mmap.c" in VSCode using the **C/C++ extension** I noticed that all the lines tagged "#include" had red lines with the following message error when I hovered over the top most "#include":

**#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\MyName\Documents\OS\mmap.c).**

I then clicked on "Quick Fix" and the first option I that popped up was "Edit '**IncludePath**'setting.". I then selected that and it brought me to the **"C/C++ Configurations"** tab. On that tab right over the section **"Compiler Path"** it states that my compiler path is **/usr/bin/gcc** however right below it there's a red box that says as follows:
***Cannot find:
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr/bin/gcc***

I can also click on the c_cpp_properties.json file given by the C/C++ extension scrolling down we find the "CompilerPath" section which states "CompilerPath:'/usr/bin/gcc'," and is underlined by a warning yellow line stating the above mentioned **"Cannot find: "**

Does anyone know what's causing this error and how I can fix my compiler path so I don't keep getting #include errors in my file?